# Unity OnCollisionEnter2D with multiple gameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I am creating a brick breaker style game. In this there are two types of bricks. One is normal brick and another is a special brick. Normal brick gets destroyed on collision with ball. Special brick duplicates the ball and then gets destroyed.

Now I have a check that whenever the remaining bricks gets to 0, game is over. I get the number of bricks at start and decrement the bricks on collision with ball.

Issue is that sometimes, the remaining bricks gets to 0 even though I can see that there are few bricks in view. I thought it was due to 2 balls colliding the brick/special brick at same time. So I added hasCollided check and resetting in LateUpdate() to avoid that but issue still seems to happen.

My code snippet:

Ball.cs

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    this.hasCollided = false;
    this.hasCollidedBrick = false;
}
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Brick")
    {
        if(this.hasCollidedBrick == true){ return; }
        this.hasCollidedBrick = true;
        GameManager.instance.ScoreUp(5);
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
    else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "SpecialBrick")
    {
        if(this.hasCollided == true){ return; }
        this.hasCollided = true;
        SceneGenerator.instance.remBalls++;
        GameManager.instance.ScoreUp(5);
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        clone = Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position,transform.rotation);
        

    }

}
```

GameManager.cs

```
public void ScoreUp(int val)
{
    score=score+val;
    if (val == 5)
    {
        remBricks--;
    }
    textScore.text = score.ToString();
    if (remBricks == 0)
    {
        winText.SetActive(true);
        textScore.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        isWin = true;
    }
}
```

Also, I dynamically generate the bricks at start using Instantiate.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The hasCollidedBrick flag must be on the brick not the ball

Comment: Also the collided with one true never destroy never happens it seems round then wrong way. But you also increment bricks killed when these never leave.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry I did not get what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for the game finishing faster than intended is `ScoreUp()` method being called more times than there are bricks, which brings us to when it's called.

> I thought it was due to 2 balls colliding the brick/special brick at same time.

Indeed, that seems to be the reason. Your check doesn't work, because the flag is set for both balls separately - both balls will pass the if statement and both will call `ScoreUp`.

As mentioned in the comments move the flag to the brick or ensure in any other way, that the method will be called only once.

I would also advise against removing (or rather decrementing) bricks based on the score:

```
score=score+val;
if (val == 5)
{
    remBricks--;
}
```

especially with magic 5 in the if statement, as it's error prone, and may cause more issues with your code later.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Should have done the other way around. The check is arbitrary and I am removing it. Thanks!